# How to use python to workout a simple mathematical problem in python with random operations

Tags: python

This is my code for a calculator that randomly selects a operation and number in between 1-10 and then with that number and operation works out the answer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nys19.png

Now heres what happens when I run the code and put in a number. It dosen't workout the question it tells you the question. How do I make it answer the question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLmaJ.png

Thank You if you help me

Comment: Please read 'How to ask' in the help centre here,  please do not post pictures of your code, instead include it in the question,

Comment: Hi , Welcome to SO! Please [do not paste images of your data][https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question], instead create an example which can be reproduced by code

Comment: You need to add code to deal with each operation, to take the two variables, perform the operation selected, and return the result to the users.  You can't just print the calculation as a string.  Please try and write code that does that, and let us know if you have a specific problem implementing it.  (e.g. `if op == '+':`   `answer = mynumber+yournumber` etc.

Comment: There are slicker ways of doing it with lambda functions etc but that's probably too advanced to help you at this stage

Comment: @JeffUK In this case it is safe to use `eval` since user input is converted to integer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell python to do something with each type of operation.

e.g.

```
operations = ['+','-']
operation = random.choice(operations)

if operation == '+':
    answer = mynumber + yournumber

if operation == '-':
    answer = mynumber - yournumber;

print(mynumber,operation,yournumber,'=',answer)
```

You would need an if statement for each operation.

A more compact and flexible approach (although more advanced) would be to have a dictionary of operations and functions that are performed for each of those operations.  Then we randomly choose an operation and send the two variables to the relevant function.  You could do this with normal functions or lambda functions like below:

```
ops = {'+':(lambda x,y:x+y),'-':(lambda x,y:x-y)}

op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))

print(yournumber,op,mynumber,"=",ops[op](yournumber,mynumber))
```

As long as you have operations that take two inputs, you can extend the list of operations infinitely without having to change the rest of the code at all.   You could then extend some of the functions to do things like error checking (check we're not dividing by zero) etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it is safe to use otherwise unsafe function `eval` for this.

Since the user can only control a number (which is actually converted to `int`, not just assumed to be a number), he can't enter any code to evaluate.

```
answer = eval(f"{yournumber} {operation} {mynumber}")
```

This will create string like `123 + 4` and then evaluate it.

**THIS IS NOT A GENERAL ADVICE**, supplying `eval` with user input might cause a vulnerability which just happened to be impossible in **your** example

Comment: If it's not general advice, and generally not a good idea,  why give it as an answer to an obvious beginner?

Comment: Sorry, @JeffUK, i am also new here. Should i delete my response?

Comment: It's not an incorrect answer!  Just with homework questions /answers one has to be aware that you might be leading OP down the wrong direction.  Teaching them that 'Eval' is an easy answer to this sort of problem may lead them to using it for everything ! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Well, that's why I mentioned that the answer is bad, explained what makes it safe here and told that it can become a vulnerability in other cases. I study information security, so I am not suporting that "eval is bad" idea. It is obvious, how eval might become a problem, but there are A LOT of functions in different languages that could lead to similar consequences if supplied with user input and exploited by a professional. This is however not the reason to discourage people from using, for example, arrays or `printf` in C++

Comment: in the same way we tell people to  "Never write your own cryptographic functions".  When someone is advanced enough to full understand why they were told that, and challenge it, then maybe it no longer applies.  In this case, it's not really a security thing, it's just the lesson is probably not 'how to mung a string into an instruction and run it through eval' rather 'how to use basic conditional structures like if statements'

Comment: This way of thinking makes some people believe that there are some "bad" things that are causing vulnerabilities and should never be used, while doing things that other people have done is completely safe.  I believe, that it is way better to teach people the real causes of vulnerabilities (like unsafe input or failed algorithms) so that they know what to look for to avoid them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241926/discussion-between-vladko312-and-jeffuk).